# How to I find the least weight(here cost) between two vertices in a Simple Directed Weight Graphs?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I have to create a program in java, using Simple Directed Weight Graphs, to find the least cost(weight) of travel between airports. This can be a direct flight. Or it can be via connections of flight. I thought of using Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm, but that gives me the shortest distance and not the least cost. For example:

```
Airport A -> Airport B = 210$
Airport A -> Airport C = 100$
Airport C -> Airport B = 100$
```

So according to this, there are two ways we can go from A to B. One is directly, which costs 210$ and the other is indirectly whose total cost is 200$(cheaper).

So if i use Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm, it would give be the first one (ie A -> B) whereas I need the answer to be A -> C -> B.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: "So if i use Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm" are you using the edge cost as the "distance"?

Comment: Why do you think Dijkstra will give you A -> B?

Comment: You can make "distance" mean weight, or cost, or any other *number* that you can *add to other numbers* in a way that makes sense and which you want to minimise.  Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't *know* that you're not talking about actual distances!  :)

Comment: Andy, no. Edge cost is actually an object of another class which stores the flight number, the departure and arrival airports and the cost of travel. 

Jiri, because A->B is a shorter distance compared to A->C->B.

j_random_hacker, I didn't really get what you mean.

Comment: What I mean is that when an algorithm (like Dijkstra's algorithm) talks about "distances", it doesn't necessarily mean *physical* distances.  Anything that you can represent numerically and treat the same way as a physical distance (you can add them, and you want to minimise the total) will work just as well, like a monetary cost or a physical weight.

Comment: So you can simply choose to *define* the "distance" from A to B as 210, for example, and the distance from A to C as 100.  Clear now?

Comment: Yup. Thanks j_random_hacker. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use dajkstra, but use price as weight, not length. Problem solved.

Comment: Actually, I tried using this, it isn't working. The thing is by length, I mean the least number of cross overs. And also,  the weight is actually an object of another class which stores the flight number, the departure and arrival airports and the cost of travel. Because I need all the details, I created a class and am using an object of that class. 

But this isn't helping me find the path with the least cost. Its just helping me find the smallest path, which is what I don't need.

Comment: @Valen - you are using it wrong or misunderstand. I do not know how exactly your data looks like, but if you create graph where nodes are airports and edges are possible travel routes between airports with weight set to price of that flight and you run Dijkstra on that, you get the cheapest route.